# How do I redirect to the cshtml page created inside shared folder in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Please help me out how do I redirect to a `.cshtml` page which is created inside a shared folder.

I want something like this

```
href="@Url.Content("Shared/UnderConstruction")"
```

Here it's not getting `redirecting` to the UnderConstruction page, which I created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC3 you can't render views directly by calling the files directly. They can only be served via controllers.

In order to call the view in your shared folder you woul have to do something similar to the following:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult About()
    {
        return View("Construction");
    }
}
```

Comment: ok . can i have somehting like @html.hiiddenfor(model.name,"name") in my cshtml so that from controller i can access the modal.name which which will have the value "name" .

Answer (score 4):

You cannot redirect to anything that's stored inside the `~/Views` folder including the `~/Views/Shared`. This folder is simply not served by ASP.NET MVC and cannot be accessed directly. Also notice that in ASP.NET MVC you are not serving .cshtml pages directly. You are always passing through controller action that return views and those views might represent .cshtml pages.

Now if you have some Shared folder directly under the site root `~/Shared`, then you can do this:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Shared/UnderConstruction")">construction</a>
```

Comment: no its not getting navigated. giving error resouce not found and that page is there in the folder.

Comment: @Rakesh, as I said in my answer .cshtml pages cannot be served directly.

Comment: ok one more thing how can i set in global.asax like any error on pages it should navigate to particular page.is this gonna work  ?? routes.MapRoute("error", "error", new { controller = "Shared", action = "UnderConstruction" });

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a page at url "shared/underconstruction" as per the other posts:

- Create controller SharedController.
- Define action "UnderConstruction"
- Create "UnderConstruction.cshtml" in Views/Shared/ folder.
- Map URL "Shared/{action}" , new { Controller = "Shared" } if you want to be explicit.

Give that a shot... to be honest even I don't know if this will work, and you will pollute your "Shared" folder. You could rename existing Shared folder to something else, maybe, and modify ViewStart.cshtml to point to new folder, maybe.

Comment: ok thanks . so how do i set same in global.asax . like instead of going to any error page it should always navigate to underconstruction

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET MVC you can only redirect to controllers, and the controllers return a view. You can access views in `Shared` the same way as your normal controller views, by their name. ASP.NET MVC first looks in your controller view folder then in your shared view folder when resolving view names.

Comment: ok just tel me how can i perform below action  <a href="@Url.Content("~/Shared/UnderConstruction")">construction</a>